# What is the difference between hasFocus() and isFocused() in android?

Tags: java, android

I understand the difference among **focused, selected and pressed**. But I don't understand the difference between `hasFocus()` and `isFocused()`. I checked the description, both descriptions say almost the same thing. Can anyone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`hasFocus()` is different from `isFocused()`. `hasFocus() == true` means that the
View or one of its descendants is focused. If you look closely,
there's a chain of hasFocused Views till you reach the View that
isFocused.

Answer (score 6):

[This should explain a bit about it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html?is-external=true)

Sometimes views in Android are grouped together, and if one of the views in that group has focus, the `hasFocus()` method will return `true`, but only when the specific view you are mentioning in code is focused will `isFocused()` equal `true`.